# Is there a way to nummerate each subcaptionbox?

Tags: captions, subcaption

I am starting to give up to my hopes, but I want to give it one last try:

Is there a way to nummerate each subcaptionbox? My code has the following build up:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\mypic{
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  % do you really need draw and fill, or just fill?
  \draw[fill] (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05]
    node[below, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small] {0};
  \draw[fill] (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05]
    node[below, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small] {1};
}

\mypic
-----
\end{tikzpicture}
% adjust vertical spacing
\par\vspace{-5pt}
% emulate the width of each drawing and the separation between them
\subcaptionbox{Dog}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
\subcaptionbox{Cat}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
\subcaptionbox{Tiger}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
\subcaptionbox{Lion}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}%


 \end{figure}
   \begin{figure}
  \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\mypic{
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  % do you really need draw and fill, or just fill?
  \draw[fill] (0.7,0) circle [radius=0.05]
    node[below, xshift=-0.2cm, font=\small] {0};
  \draw[fill] (2.3,0) circle [radius=0.05]
    node[below, xshift=0.2cm, font=\small] {1};
}

 \mypic
  -----  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
   % adjust vertical spacing
      \par\vspace{-5pt}
        % emulate the width of each drawing and the separation between them
    \subcaptionbox{X}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
    \subcaptionbox{Y}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
        \subcaptionbox{Z}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}\hspace{1.25cm}%
          \subcaptionbox{D}{\rule{3cm}{0pt}}%
         \end{figure}
```

And so I would like to have 1. Dog, 2. Cat, 3. Lion, etc... The thing is, I could do this manually, but I have 7000 lines of code like this, and I would rather not do this manually. Is there an easy trick to nummerate every subcaptionbox? I would be very happy hearing about it. Also, as a build up, my code has basically 16 figures on one page. So it is 4 x 4, which is why I took the approach of the subcaptionbox. Besides that, it would be great to have a method that doesn't take that much more effort than doing 1., 2. etc manually. I was thinking of something like \newcounter{subboxcounter}

\setcounter{subboxcounter}{1} and somehow inserting the number into the caption, but I would have no idea how to do it. Could someone help?

Comment: Hello! Can you add the result to have an example? If you use subfig package?

Comment: Please post complete code we can compile. If you call the sub-figures 1, 2, 3 etc., how will you distinguish the third sub-figure from the third figure? Do you not have any figure-level captions at all? If so, why not just use caption rather than sub-caption? Note that sub-figures are numbered by default if you are using `subcaption`, so if they aren't numbered at all, it's because of some code you've not shown. (They may get letters rather than numbers by default - I can't remember.)

Comment: You can apply these steps to spot, what we miss, and significantly improve your posted code in almost no time : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137